# Setting style for dynamically added buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set the style to a dynamically added buttons in an activity but the buttons are still with the default stlye.

Here is **my activity**

```
package com.sample.Learn_German_Quiz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.interpolator.linear;


public class LessonChooserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GrammarBank grammarBank = new GrammarBank();

    public String getSelectedLesson() {
        return selectedLesson;
    }

    public void setSelectedLesson(String selectedLesson) {
        this.selectedLesson = selectedLesson;
    }

    private String selectedLesson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_chooser);
        grammarBank.initLessons(getApplicationContext());
        setupButton();


    }


    private void setupButton() {


        Context newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), R.style.button_learn);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearTest);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            Button btn = new Button(newContext);
            //Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setText(grammarBank.getLessonTitle(i));
            layout.addView(btn);
        }


    }


}
```

and the **layout** file for the **activity**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:id="@+id/linearTest">

    <Button
        style="@style/button_learn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"

        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the **style** I want to give to my buttons:

```
 <style name="button_learn" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_rounded</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

**button_rounded.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="50dp"></corners>
         <solid android:color="#4F535F"></solid>

    </shape>

</item>


</selector>
```

They are showing like this:

[image]

and I want them like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearTest);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        Button btn= new Button(this, null,R.style.button_learn);
        btn.setText(grammarBank.getLessonTitle(i));
        layout.addView(btn);
    }
```

Comment: Great that's exactly what I was looking for, to help others please change Button **button** to Button **btn** :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using another [Button constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet,%20int)) that takes also int defStyleAttr? If you pass R.style.button_learn as defStyleAttr then it should work.

Comment: Thanks haaawk for the great answer ! I kind of combined your answer with the one of **Mubashar Javed** and made it work :)